# A person who is biased to person x's advice

Tags: word-choice

What do you call a person who is biased towards ones opinion or advice. 
For example, Person will mostly reject an opinion from person x and never from person y.

I know of 'Opinionated' and 'Biased'. But looking for a more specific word.

For example, King X is biased towards the opinion of his adviser x than adviser y.

Comment: Could you explain why *biased* is not specific enough for you? Are you looking for a single word or a phrase?

Comment: You could say that **the king strongly favors John's advice over Jack's**.

Comment: I was wanting a specific word.

Comment: I agree a phrase is more descriptive.